layers.Dense - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank' "
Getting the error "AttributeError: ‘tuple’ object has no attribute ‘rank’ " on the line :
dense = layers.Dense(4, activation=act_func)(inputs),
in the following function :
def gen_model(act_func = 'relu'):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(4,))
    dense = layers.Dense(4, activation=act_func)(inputs)
    dense = layers.Dense(4, activation=act_func)(dense)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1)(dense)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="NN_heat_controller")
    return model

if I just print out variable “inputs”, it is :
“<KerasTensor shape=(None, 4), dtype=float32, sparse=None, name=keras_tensor_1>”
As far as I understand, the layers.Dense function is expecting a symbolic tensor and that is what is being input as well.

Please post the full error traceback.

Hi @Muhannad ,Will you please check that you are using correct importing lines 'from tensorflow.keras import layers'
'from tensorflow import keras'  and Try running this and see if the error still occurs. If it does, please provide the full code so that I can help you further. Thank you.
